# WPquery + add row every nth element

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, counter

So the case if following - i've got a wpquery like on the code below.

```
<section class="row service_block_row bgf" id="page-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <?php
                        $args = array(
                        'post_type'      => 'page',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
                        'order'          => 'ASC',
                        'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
                     );


                    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );

                    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : ?>

                        <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
                                <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>

                        <?php endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

What I would like to achieve is to have the loop working like that:

```
<ROW>
<COL-LG-3>
<COL-LG-3>
<COL-LG-3>
<COL-LG-3>
</ROW>
```

SO in fact what i would lke to achieve is to have 4 elements inside row without creating different loops. I know i should use some counter but i have no clue how;/

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add new row after 4 cols**

```
<section class="row service_block_row bgf" id="page-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <?php
                        $args = array(
                        'post_type'      => 'page',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'post_parent'    => $post->ID,
                        'order'          => 'ASC',
                        'orderby'        => 'menu_order'
                     );


                    $parent = new WP_Query( $args );

                    if ( $parent->have_posts() ) : 
                     $count=0;
                    ?>
                        <div class="row">
                        <?php while ( $parent->have_posts() ) : $parent->the_post(); 
                            $count++;
                        ?>
                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
                                <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
                            </div>

                        <?php 
                        if($count%4==0)
                        {
                            echo '</div><div class="row">';
                        }
                        endwhile; ?>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```